# Formulas Throw Invalid Reference

Tags: excel, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that has just over 1K rows on it, and I am wanting to get a list of what ID's exist in the second worksheet that holds roughly 600 rows.  I have tried using the `VLOOKUP()`, `IF()`, `COUNTIF()` functions, but each one gives me an error of

> Invalid reference.  
> This file version can only have formulas that reference cells within a worksheet size of 256 columns (column IW or higher) or 65536 rows.

What do I need to do so that I am able to compare these two lists?

VLookup() I used = `=VLOOKUP(A3,[Book1]Sheet1!$A:$K,2,false)`
CountIF() I used = `=COUNTIF([Book1]Sheet1!$A:$A,D1)`

Comment: I'd suggest including the formulas themselves in your question

Comment: @Alfabravo - sorry meant to include them initially.

Comment: Are you working in excel 2013 with a .xls file? If you work in a .xlsx file it might work. Also, you'd try not using the whole $A | $K column. Just guessing

Comment: Agree with @Alfabravo. Save your file as *.xlsx extension or *.xlsm if it is macro enabled and then close it and reopen the file. It should solve your issue i think.

Comment: @Alfabravo - that solved my issue.  I did not realize I was trying to compare an .xlsx to a .xls

Comment: Ok, i've set it up as answer so others can find it easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the thing with recent versions is about formulas working on a compatibility mode. Having more/less rows available brings up these kind of errors.

Are you working in excel 2013 with a .xls file? If you switch to work in a .xlsx file it might just work.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get this error after converting your XLS file to XLSX, try closing the file completely and then reopening it.  It fixed the issue for me.